# Deal with unsupported cursors in different browsers

Tags: html, css

I want to change the cursor to cell(thick plus sign) on the hover of table cell

i used

```
tr:hover td {
    cursor: cell;
}
```

Looks like it doesnot work in chrome, but works in firefox.

list of cursors 
http://www.css3.com/css-cursor/
and
http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-cursor-styles/#fbid=2MQ0iRM9or2
say that it is supported in chrome.

one work aroud can be creating an image for the cursor.

i am looking any other better workaround/

or what are the best practices for managing cursors for different browsers.

Comment: Seems to work fine in Chrome for me: http://jsbin.com/emovid

Comment: What version are you running? Maybe upgrade?

Comment: version: 17.0.963.79 for linux(debian)

Comment: I'm running 18. Maybe try that?

Comment: Working on v16(mine) and Opera 11.62

Comment: @mashit to clarify, are you looking at my link, or your page? Check to see if the cursor works on the page I linked to.

Comment: no its doesnot work for the above jsbin also. so its browser version problem. but i cant tell users to upgrade. so looking for a work around

Comment: Well, Chrome has lots of versions...lots have bugs. I wouldn't go nuts trying to keep ahead of those. Also, cursors are meant to be a nice-to-have and shouldn't break anything you build. In other words, I wouldn't even try to come up with a workaround for this. Let it just degrade gracefully. Otherwise, you could try using your own cursor files: http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2008/01/08/cross-browser-custom-css-cursors/

Comment: Also, experiment to see if it's actually the cursor style that isn't working, or that particular CSS selector. If it's the selector, maybe there's a different way to go about it for that version for Chrome

Comment: @pankaj that's my username on some of the other SE sites

Comment: @DA. can you please post your comments as an answer? they were useful.

Comment: @DA. yes I have seen your profile you are a big boy :D please come in the GD chat whenever you have time I have doubts to clear with someone who really have knowledge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firefox, the cell cursor seems to default to a cross-hair. I would simply set your cursor and leave it to the browser to then decide what to do with it. In other words, keep the CSS you have, and so long as the cursor you want is a standard in the specs, it'll slowly be adopted over time and have a level of graceful degradation.

Your other option is to use JavaScript. If you like jQuery, there seem to be a few plugins around that will do this with an image.

Here's one I dug up that seems simple enough:

http://jquery.kidsil.net/examples/customcursor/example.html

Good luck!